# Show only values that are set

Tags: jquery

I have the following script that is working totally fine. that does some calculation on two fields and shows in a third field.

```
     $(function() {
     $(document).on('change', 'td.evaluation select', function() {
        var gap = parseInt($(this).find(':selected').val())- parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('td.mefly').text()) ;

        $(this).parents('tr').find('td.gap input:text').val(gap);
        if(gap<0){
         $(this).parents('tr').find('td.gap input:text').css('background-color','red');
        }else  $(this).parents('tr').find('td.gap input:text').css('background-color','#3CB371');

     });
  });
```

Now I wanted to add a script to run the script on load of the page, with the values that have been stored previously. But it keeps the result blank.
Here is what I tried:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var gap = parseInt($("td.evaluation select").find(':selected').val())- parseInt($("td.evaluation select").parents('tr').find('td.mefly').text()) ;

            $("td.evaluation select").parents('tr').find('td.gap input:text').val(gap);
            if(gap<0){
                $("td.evaluation select").parents('tr').find('td.gap input:text').css('background-color','red');
            }else  $("td.evaluation select").parents('tr').find('td.gap input:text').css('background-color','#3CB371');

        }

    )};
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: stored where? Soon as you reload the page you start from a blank slate unless you are using cookies or something.

Comment: Stored in the Database. I reload them in the selects after they are saved.

Comment: do you get an error? have you done any debugging e.g. console.log() etc.